# Only show first image in foreach loop

Tags: php, posts, loop, images, array

My loop shows a list of values, and underneath them, the post title and image for the value.

The problem is that because some values are associated with multiple posts, multiple images show up. I only need one image. Is there any way to show only the first image in my `foreach` loop?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_key'      => 'colors',
));

$results = [];
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $the_query->the_post(); 
    $credits = get_field('colors');

    if( !empty($color) ) {

        foreach( $colors as $color ) {  
           $results [$color][]=array(
               'title' => get_the_title(),
               'img' => get_field('photo')
           );
       }
    }
}

foreach ($results as $color => $posts) {

   foreach($posts as $post) {  /* This shows multiple images but I only need one */
        echo '<img src="'.$post['img']['url'].'">';
    }


   echo '<div><h2>'.$color.'</h2>';

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo '<div>'.$post['title'].'</div>';
    }

   echo '</div>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of what you are exactly trying to achieve accessing the first element of the `$posts` array may work for you. No need for the `foreach` loop.

```
echo '<img src="'.$posts[0]['img']['url'].'">';
```

Comment: Yes, this is working! Thank you